# My Fetched Results Controller Is Not sorting newer entries among the old entries

Tags: swift, core-data, uikit, nsfetchedresultscontroller, core-data-migration

I have 7 tableviews, one for each day. I add lesson models, with name, starTime, endtime, etc to the day tables, saved to core data. My NSFetchedResultsControlller subclass has 7 instances for each day. 
It is sorting the entries based on startTime on each table . Everything was working fine on my 0.0, 0.1 of my app. I had a lightweight migration between 0.1, 0.1.1. That only meant adding a new property called "notes (String)".
 Migration looked successful. Nothing was crashing, everything seemed to work. 
PROBLEM:
Only recently I realized, when I am adding a new entry with a startTime, my fetchedResultsController does not count with the old existing entries.
For example I have an older list from two weeks ago, (– probably from before the last app update):

- xy 14:00
- yy 14:30
- zz 18:00
- xyz 19:00

When I am adding a new entry to the list, doesn't matter it has 10:00 startTime, it adds to the end of the line:

- xy 14:00
- yy 14:30
- zz 18:00
- xyz 19:00
- new 10:00

however, when I keep adding new entries, they are sorted among the new entries. Let's add an entry with 9:00, what happens is:

- xy 14:00
- yy 14:30
- zz 18:00
- xyz 19:00
- newest 9:00
- new 10:00

So the sorting is working among the new entries.
What's even more interesting, sorting is also working among the old entries, so If I change an old entry, for ex. yy to have 13:00, the result is:

- yy 13:30
- xy 14:00
- zz 18:00
- xyz 19:00
- newest 9:00
- new 10:00

But still the new are not considered here.

Anyone has an Idea what can cause this? Is it maybe about my lightweight migration? I think it would be a very bad user experience to reload their tables every time an update is coming.
Thanks everyone for taking your time!

UPDATE:

It is probably because an absolute date time is set to my entries, however i just wanted to set a relative time, as my application is a class timetable kind of tool. Maybe the real question is, how to make it independent of actual dates?

my FRC :

```
  import CoreData

class DayFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Lesson> {

override init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Lesson> = Lesson.fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext =  CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: String? = nil , cacheName name: String? = nil) {

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)]

    super.init(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: name)
}

func setDayPredicate(_ formatString:String = "dayNumber = %i", day: Int )  {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: formatString, day)
    self.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
}

func fetch(day: Int) {
         setDayPredicate("dayNumber = %i", day: day)
          do {
                try self.performFetch()

            }  catch let fetchErr {
                    print("Failed to fetch results", fetchErr)
                }
      }
}
```

on my main VC:

```
    lazy var mondayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
 let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
  frc.fetch(day: 0)
  frc.delegate = self
 return frc
}()

lazy var tuesdayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
 let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
  frc.fetch(day: 1)
  frc.delegate = self
 return frc
    }()

lazy var wednesdayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
 let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
 frc.fetch(day: 2)
  frc.delegate = self
 return frc
    }()

lazy var thursdayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
 let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
  frc.fetch(day: 3)
  frc.delegate = self
 return frc
      }()

lazy var fridayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
 let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
  frc.fetch(day: 4)
  frc.delegate = self
 return frc
        }()

lazy var saturdayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
 frc.fetch(day: 5)
 frc.delegate = self
return frc
       }()

lazy var sundayFetchedResultsController: DayFetchedResultsController = {
let frc = DayFetchedResultsController()
 frc.fetch(day: 6)
 frc.delegate = self
return frc
       }()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have found out.
I am saving my model objects with a startTime property, like 9:00, but in reality the whole current date is saved together with year, month, day. Console is showing that clearly. That is not what I wanted.

Here' the fix:

I added a new DateComponents() variable. I set its year, month, day to 2001.01.01. Then I let my  datePicker set the hours, minutes.

```
var dateComponents: DateComponents = {
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.year = 2001
dc.month = 1
dc.day = 1
return dc
}()

  dateComponents.hour = formatter.calendar.component(.hour, from: datePicker.date)
         dateComponents.minute = formatter.calendar.component(.minute, from: datePicker.date)
        startTime = formatter.calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? Date()
```

Comment: Actually I do not know how to do that, since I am using a datePicker to set the times.  DatePickers have a date, even when they are not displaying it.